# javascript behavior not functioning when i do browser preview from dreamweaver,

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Divs</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
   <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>word</div>
        <div>word</div>
        <div>word</div>
        <div>word</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is my css code:

```
div {
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:50px;
}
```

here is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('div').mouseenter(function() {
       $(this).animate({
           height: '+=10px'
       });
   });
   $('div').mouseleave(function() {
       $(this).animate({
           height: '-=10px'
       }); 
   });
   $('div').click(function() {
       $(this).fadeOut(1000);
   }); 
});
```

When I do browser preview or live code in dreamweaver, the click handler or animation isn't firing, is my code wrong, or are the program settings wrong, I'm lost (I've tried it on chrome, firefox and safari).

Comment: the duration is 1000ms =1sec try some large value............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this link before your script.js

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">     </script>
```

this is jquery link without this your jquery script not functioning. always when you use jquery you have to put jquery.js you can know more about this on

http://jquery.com/

Comment: sorry i'm very new to coding, in the line you've given above, where would the script.js file be referenced?

Comment: you have not referenced your script.js just put this before script.js

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Dreamweaver manages its environment, but your script looks like it's using jQuery but your html isn't loading that library.

Try opening the developer console in one of your browsers and look for a JavaScript error, you will probably see something like `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Copy the script tags from the [jQuery download page](http://jquery.com/download/#using-jquery-with-a-cdn). jQuery should be loaded before your script does, so your document `<head>` would look like this:

```
<head>
    <title>Divs</title>
    <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
```

Here's a JSFiddle showing your code working:  http://jsfiddle.net/qD35V/  You can use the Frameworks menu on the sidebar to turn jQuery on and off.

Comment: all my jquery code is written in the script.js file that the html references, i'm just befuddled, i see the reference error, what's the next step?

Comment: You need to include the jQuery library, your script calls jQuery commands, but it doesn't include the library itself.